# Not getting didregisterdevice getting called with UIapplication.registerforemotenotification, for this I have to get user permission to get it called

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to APNS get device token in iOS without a prompt for user permission.
But only with UIapplication.registerforemotenotification in didfinsih launch I am not getting did register delegate get called it only gets called when user gives permission.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the relevant code

Comment: Please provide the code that you have implemented. That will bring in more clarity to our question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present notification banners/alerts, you must obtain user's permission for push notifications. If you only need silent push notifications (in order to be able to send updates to the app), you can enable background mode - "Remote Notifications". In this case, you will get a token, even if you don't get the user's permission, but remember that banners will not be visible.

Comment: This solution working great, but for some devices its not generating device token is that [possible?

Comment: @HarshThakur can you try presenting the notification permission? With background mode enabled, you should get the token regardless of user's decision

Comment: here requirement is to pass token to server prior to permissions

Comment: @HarshThakur is it possible to move the code that asks for permission to the very app start? Some apps do it after login, but there are lots of other apps that present the alert immediately on app launch? You can keep other permission requests to be presented at a later point